# How to configure svn ignore settings with git svn?

Tags: svn, git-svn, svnignore, svn-propset

I know I can configure folders and files for being ignored by subversion using the following commands:

```
svn propset svn:ignore build . // Ignores the build folder.
svn propedit svn:ignore . // Opens an editor.
```

Though, I use `git svn` to checkout a repository stored on a subversion server. I could not find a command to do the configuration this way. The following list shows all commands that are suggested by `zsh` completion for `git svn`:

```
$ git svn
blame           -- show what revision and author last modified each line of a file:
branch          -- create a branch in the SVN repository
clone           -- same as init, followed by fetch
commit-diff     -- commit diff of two tree-ishs
create-ignore   -- recursively finds the svn:ignore property and creates .gitignore files
dcommit         -- commit diffs from given head onto SVN repository
fetch           -- fetch revisions from the SVN remote
find-rev        -- output git commit corresponding to the given SVN revision's hash
info            -- show information about a file or directory
init            -- initialize an empty git repository with additional svn data
log             -- output SVN log-messages
propget         -- get a given SVN property for a file
proplist        -- list the SVN properties stored for a file or directory
rebase          -- fetch revs from SVN parent of HEAD and rebase current work on it
set-tree        -- commit given commit or tree to SVN repository
show-externals  -- show the subversion externals
show-ignore     -- output corresponding toplevel .gitignore file of svn:ignore
tag             -- create a tag in the SVN repository
```

**Question:**

- Do you know if there is any way to edit the subversion ignore configuration via `git svn`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, git-svn supports only creation of .gitignore by svn:ignore. To set svn:ignore you may

1. Use `svn propset svn:ignore 'value' URL` where URL can be obtained by (`git-svn git svn info path/to/directory | awk '/URL:/{print $2}'`) So you may write your own 'svn_propset.sh' script. To sync your .gitignore with svn:ignore run `git svn create-ignore`
2. Use any of tools that allow .gitignore <-> svn:ignore translation. I know only two: [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) (client side, note: you need a fresh clone to turn ignores support on) and [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) (server side, you need to have access to the server with SVN). In this case svn:ignore is set on pushing your local commit to the SVN(for SmartGit)/Git(for SubGit) repository.